# Retrieve HTML from database, and format it as html instead of plain text

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database query that returns the raw HTML for a page, but if I use it on my page, it gets shown as plain text (of course). How would I format it as HTML so that it uses the tags and such.

An example of what I have in my database:

```
<div class="test">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
```

But it is also displayed like that. I would like it to format the text as if it was HTML. So it would just display:

> SOME TEXT HERE

But that it would also be in a div with the class: "test"

What would be the best approach to reach this goal?

Im using Twig in the MVC model to render the page. So the page renderer is like this

```
    public function renderArticle() {
        $twig = new TwigHelper();
        $args['title'] = "Artikel $this->articleId";
        $args['blogHTML'] = BlogController::retrieveBlogHTML($this->articleId);
        echo $twig->render('article.twig', $args);
     }
```

And the "BlogController::retrieveBlogHTML" goes like this:

```
    public static function retrieveBlogHTML($id) {
    $db = DatabaseHelper::get();
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT PageHTML FROM T_Blog WHERE BlogId = :BlogId");
    $st->execute([
        ':BlogId' => $id,
    ]);
    if ($st->errorCode() !== \PDO::ERR_NONE) {
        return null;
    }
    return $st->fetchAll();
}
```

This means that I will not be able to use JavaScript at this point in time, if that will be the only way to fix the problem i'll have to build a workaround.

So I dont know if I accidently escape too or something along those lines, but im not using any headers.

Comment: How do you retrieve the div ? Ajax ? Server side code ?

Comment: That's probably a matter of setting the right content headers, or maybe you accidentally escaped the HTML. You should really give more details and some code of your current process.

Comment: Im sorry for my late response, but I have updated my main post with some more information on how I retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the html characters (so `<` becomes `&lt;` for example).

In javascript you can use the [HE library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) or theres this function, which is generally fine, but doesn't cover all possible cases that the HE library does

```
var encodedStr = rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
   return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

If your using php you can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), other languages will have a similar function either inbuilt or provided via a library.

Comment: Im not using Javascript at this moment to retrieve the data. I updated my main post to show how I retrieve the information. Sorry for the late answer btw.

Comment: I thought twig defaulted to autoescaping? In any case you can force html escaping by using `{{ blogHTML.PageHTML|e }}` or `{{ blogHTML.PageHTML|escape }}`. See here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html